# Error Module parse failed: Unexpected token - Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I am having trouble with the webpack, just added a new component from another project and the console error are in the attachment, and this is my const config in `webpack.config.js`:

```
const config = {
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
                            plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime', 'react-hot-loader/babel']
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: ['style-loader', 'raw-loader']
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ template: './src/index.html' })]
    }
```

[image: console error]

Comment: is this the full webpack config or a snippet of it?

Comment: The rest of the file is just configuring development and production variables!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to remove `exclude: /node_modules/,` from your `module.rules[0] configuration.

The file that you are trying to compile is in `node_modules` and it needs `babel-loader` with `@babel/preset-react` present to compile it.

You can also define the regex such as it will exclude all node_modules besides this file.